# Restricting amount of foreign rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables, foreign-keys

How do I restrict how many entities of a foreign table that can be "added" under a table.

For instance, I have a case where we can have a maximum of 3 employees at break at a time.
I created break as a table where employee ID would become a foreign reference.

Comment: That really sounds like something that should probably be done in application code, but I suppose it could be implemented in a BEFORE INSERT trigger that raises an error preventing the insertion if the table already has three rows.

Comment: A trigger solution would be subject to a race condition.

Comment: You can build the logic into the INSERT  itself